# Converting (or getting) Matplotlib to find Helvetica (or equivalent) non-tff font files

Tags: python, matplotlib, fonts

I am working on RHEL 8.6.  I am using `Python-3.6.8` and `matplotlib-3.0.3`.  I am trying to get Matplotlib to use Helvetica (or an Open Source Clone).  I followed Red Hat's [instructions](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/6957193) on installing it :

```
$ dnf install xorg-x11-fonts-*
$ cat /etc/fonts/conf.d/01-xorg-x11-fonts.conf  # Created this file...
<!DOCTYPE fontconfig SYSTEM "fonts.dtd">
<fontconfig>
    <dir>/usr/share/X11/fonts/75dpi</dir>
    <dir>/usr/share/X11/fonts/100dpi</dir>
</fontconfig>
$ fc-cache -fv
$ fc-list | grep -i helvetica
/usr/share/X11/fonts/75dpi/helvR24-ISO8859-1.pcf.gz: Helvetica:style=Regular
/usr/share/X11/fonts/75dpi/helvBO08.pcf.gz: Helvetica:style=Bold Oblique
.
.
.
/usr/share/X11/fonts/100dpi/helvB24-ISO8859-1.pcf.gz: Helvetica:style=Bold
/usr/share/X11/fonts/75dpi/helvBO18.pcf.gz: Helvetica:style=Bold Oblique

$ rm -rf ~/.cache/matplotlib/  # As suggested by several posts
```

In Python, I checked to see what fonts are available and so I did :

```
$ python
Python 3.6.8 (default, May 31 2023, 10:28:59)
[GCC 8.5.0 20210514 (Red Hat 8.5.0-18)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import matplotlib.font_manager
>>> matplotlib.font_manager.findSystemFonts(fontpaths=None, fontext='ttf')
['/usr/share/fonts/msttcorefonts/ariali.ttf', '/usr/share/fonts/msttcorefonts/courbi.ttf', '/usr/share/fonts/msttcorefonts/trebucbd.ttf', '/usr/share/fonts/msttcorefonts/ariblk.ttf', '/usr/share/fonts/google-droid/DroidSansDevanagari-Regular.ttf', '/usr/share/fonts/dejavu/DejaVuSans-Bold.ttf', '/usr/share/fonts/urw-base35/NimbusMonoPS-Italic.otf', '/usr/share/fonts/urw-base35/NimbusRoman-Italic.otf', '/usr/share/fonts/google-droid/DroidSansGeorgian.ttf', '/usr/share/fonts/google-droid/DroidSansHebrew-Bold.ttf', '/usr/share/fonts/msttcorefonts/georgiai.ttf', '/usr/share/fonts/msttcorefonts/trebucbi.ttf', '/usr/share/fonts/dejavu/DejaVuSansCondensed-Bold.ttf', '/usr/share/fonts/liberation-sans/LiberationSans-Regular.ttf', '/usr/share/fonts/msttcorefonts/arial.ttf', '/usr/share/fonts/google-droid/DroidSansJapanese.ttf', '/usr/share/fonts/msttcorefonts/impact.ttf', '/usr/share/fonts/google-droid/DroidSansEthiopic-Regular.ttf', '/usr/share/fonts/google-droid/DroidSans.ttf', '/usr/share/fonts/msttcorefonts/webdings.ttf', '/usr/share/fonts/urw-base35/NimbusMonoPS-Bold.otf', '/usr/share/fonts/urw-base35/URWGothic-Demi.otf', '/usr/share/fonts/dejavu/DejaVuSansMono-Bold.ttf', '/usr/share/fonts/msttcorefonts/andalemo.ttf', '/usr/share/fonts/msttcorefonts/cour.ttf', '/usr/share/fonts/msttcorefonts/verdanab.ttf', '/usr/share/fonts/msttcorefonts/verdana.ttf', '/usr/share/fonts/urw-base35/NimbusRoman-Bold.otf', '/usr/share/fonts/google-droid/DroidSansArabic.ttf', '/usr/share/fonts/urw-base35/P052-Roman.otf', '/usr/share/fonts/urw-base35/URWBookman-Light.otf', '/usr/share/fonts/urw-base35/URWGothic-DemiOblique.otf', '/usr/share/fonts/urw-base35/C059-Bold.otf', '/usr/share/fonts/msttcorefonts/times.ttf', '/usr/share/fonts/urw-base35/NimbusSansNarrow-Regular.otf', '/usr/share/fonts/abattis-cantarell/Cantarell-BoldOblique.otf', '/usr/share/fonts/urw-base35/NimbusRoman-Regular.otf', '/usr/share/fonts/urw-base35/C059-BdIta.otf', '/usr/share/fonts/urw-base35/P052-Italic.otf', '/usr/share/fonts/urw-base35/URWBookman-Demi.otf', '/usr/share/fonts/urw-base35/Z003-MediumItalic.otf', '/usr/share/fonts/urw-base35/NimbusSans-Bold.otf', '/usr/share/fonts/urw-base35/URWGothic-BookOblique.otf', '/usr/share/fonts/msttcorefonts/arialbi.ttf', '/usr/share/fonts/urw-base35/NimbusSansNarrow-Bold.otf', '/usr/share/fonts/google-droid/DroidSansArmenian.ttf', '/usr/share/fonts/msttcorefonts/comicbd.ttf', '/usr/share/fonts/urw-base35/C059-Roman.otf', '/usr/share/fonts/google-droid/DroidSansThai.ttf', '/usr/share/fonts/dejavu/DejaVuSansMono-BoldOblique.ttf', '/usr/share/fonts/msttcorefonts/courbd.ttf', '/usr/share/fonts/urw-base35/NimbusSans-Italic.otf', '/usr/share/fonts/msttcorefonts/timesbd.ttf', '/usr/share/fonts/msttcorefonts/verdanaz.ttf', '/usr/share/fonts/abattis-cantarell/Cantarell-Bold.otf', '/usr/share/fonts/msttcorefonts/couri.ttf', '/usr/share/fonts/google-droid/DroidSans-Bold.ttf', '/usr/share/fonts/dejavu/DejaVuSans-BoldOblique.ttf', '/usr/share/fonts/urw-base35/URWBookman-DemiItalic.otf', '/usr/share/fonts/msttcorefonts/verdanai.ttf', '/usr/share/fonts/dejavu/DejaVuSans-Oblique.ttf', '/usr/share/fonts/urw-base35/NimbusSansNarrow-Oblique.otf', '/usr/share/fonts/dejavu/DejaVuSans.ttf', '/usr/share/fonts/google-droid/DroidSansFallback.ttf', '/usr/share/fonts/urw-base35/URWGothic-Book.otf', '/usr/share/fonts/urw-base35/NimbusMonoPS-Regular.otf', '/usr/share/fonts/msttcorefonts/trebuc.ttf', '/usr/share/fonts/dejavu/DejaVuSansMono.ttf', '/usr/share/fonts/urw-base35/P052-BoldItalic.otf', '/usr/share/fonts/urw-base35/P052-Bold.otf', '/usr/share/fonts/dejavu/DejaVuSansCondensed-Oblique.ttf', '/usr/share/fonts/msttcorefonts/timesbi.ttf', '/usr/share/fonts/google-droid/DroidSansTamil-Bold.ttf', '/usr/share/fonts/google-droid/DroidSansTamil-Regular.ttf', '/usr/share/fonts/urw-base35/NimbusSans-BoldItalic.otf', '/usr/share/fonts/urw-base35/C059-Italic.otf', '/usr/share/X11/fonts/TTF/GohaTibebZemen.ttf', '/usr/share/fonts/google-droid/DroidSansHebrew-Regular.ttf', '/usr/share/fonts/urw-base35/NimbusSansNarrow-BoldOblique.otf', '/usr/share/fonts/msttcorefonts/georgia.ttf', '/usr/share/fonts/google-droid/DroidSansEthiopic-Bold.ttf', '/usr/share/fonts/dejavu/DejaVuSansCondensed.ttf', '/usr/share/fonts/urw-base35/NimbusSans-Regular.otf', '/usr/share/fonts/dejavu/DejaVuSans-ExtraLight.ttf', '/usr/share/fonts/liberation-sans/LiberationSans-Bold.ttf', '/usr/share/fonts/msttcorefonts/comic.ttf', '/usr/share/fonts/abattis-cantarell/Cantarell-Oblique.otf', '/usr/share/fonts/urw-base35/NimbusRoman-BoldItalic.otf', '/usr/share/fonts/urw-base35/D050000L.otf', '/usr/share/fonts/msttcorefonts/arialbd.ttf', '/usr/share/fonts/dejavu/DejaVuSansMono-Oblique.ttf', '/usr/share/fonts/msttcorefonts/trebucit.ttf', '/usr/share/fonts/urw-base35/URWBookman-LightItalic.otf', '/usr/share/fonts/dejavu/DejaVuSansCondensed-BoldOblique.ttf', '/usr/share/fonts/liberation-sans/LiberationSans-BoldItalic.ttf', '/usr/share/fonts/msttcorefonts/tahoma.ttf', '/usr/share/fonts/msttcorefonts/timesi.ttf', '/usr/share/fonts/abattis-cantarell/Cantarell-Regular.otf', '/usr/share/fonts/liberation-sans/LiberationSans-Italic.ttf', '/usr/share/fonts/urw-base35/NimbusMonoPS-BoldItalic.otf', '/usr/share/fonts/msttcorefonts/georgiab.ttf', '/usr/share/fonts/msttcorefonts/georgiaz.ttf']
```

Clearly, the fonts in `/usr/share/X11/fonts/*/*.pcf.gz` are not being found by matplotlib.
I also have Tex Gyre installed (where [Tex Gyre Heros](https://www.gust.org.pl/projects/e-foundry/tex-gyre/heros/index_html) is also a Helvetica replacement)

```
$ dnf repoquery -l texlive-tex-gyre
Not root, Subscription Management repositories not updated
Last metadata expiration check: 0:23:21 ago on Thu 21 Sep 2023 08:58:10 AM EDT.
/usr/share/licenses/texlive-tex-gyre
.
.
.
$ find /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/doc/fonts/tex-gyre/ -name "*.ttf" -print
$ find /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/doc/fonts/tex-gyre/ -name "*.otf" -print
```

According to the [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/font_manager_api.html), matplotlib's font manager can only use `*.ttf` and `*.afm`.

Question :

1. Is there a way to convert or otherwise get matplotlib to find (and use) the non-ttf fonts installed in `/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/doc/fonts/tex-gyre/` or `/usr/share/X11/fonts/*/*.pcf.gz`?